# Where is "Implement Interface" context menu item in visual studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

In Visual studio 2015, "Implement Interface" option is missing. Is it possible to customize Context Menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VS 2015 Professional, there is no direct `Implement Interface` context menu available. Instead, VS provided `Quick Action (Ctrl + .)` context menu. There you can find the Implement Interface context menu.

[image]

Comment: When I use Resharper this option is not been invoked.. Any Idea how to avoid this?

Comment: @SukeshChand No, I haven't used Resharper.